# How to change the color of this line in CLion

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I've checked some options in the "Editor -> Color Scheme -> General", but they do not work.

I want to customize the color of this line or close this line (it's best to be able to customize colors).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?
[image: Setting option]

Comment: Most likely OP is after that vertical dark gray line, that starts at `{` and ends at `}` lines.

Comment: no,but thanks.
It is the connection between the first and last line numbers of the current code block